# Mysql: where clause - filter information

Tags: mysql

considering the following query and output:

```
MariaDB [cf]> SELECT user_name, target_id 
              FROM table_google_apps 
              WHERE user_name LIKE "%stepha%" OR user_name LIKE "%tobias%" 
              LIMIT 5;

+----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| user_name      | target_id                                    |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Stephan B      | 1S4H-FfVVkDG2kcJKyaZqnmLhVYSRIrZDlkRGQQ9P0Go |
| Stephan B      | 1qzkKgYKXeZ671dmLswp-BFyF-cs4NtobZlt0KmE6mwg |
| Stephan B      | 0B_qFxWHs9u2naGdRSlktY1dwR0E                 |
| Tobias S       | 1qzkKgYKXeZ671dmLswp-BFyF-cs4NtobZlt0KmE6mwg |
| Stephan        | 0B_qFxWHs9u2nOVdLQW4taXkycG8                 |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

One can clearly see that Stephan and Tobias worked on the same document (`target id 1qzkKgYKXeZ671dmLswp-BFyF-cs4NtobZlt0KmE6mwg`). How can I write a query that will only return information where the target_id from stephan is equal to the target_id form tobias?

For example: ...`where stephan.target_id = tobias.target_id`..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_name, t1.target_id 
FROM table_google_apps AS t1
INNER JOIN table_google_apps AS t2 
   ON t1.target_id = t2.target_id AND t1.user_name <> t2.user_name
WHERE t1.user_name LIKE "%stepha%" OR t1.user_name LIKE "%tobias%" 
LIMIT 5;
```

The query joins the table to itself based on the *same* `target_id` value *and different* `user_name` values. Hence it returns `user_name` values sharing the same `target_id` value.

**Note:** The query works as long as you are only interested in pairs of `user_name` values sharing the same `target_id` value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/850e95/1)

Answer (score 0):

This would give you all the users of a file:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(user_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS users,
  COUNT(*) AS user_count,
  target_id 
FROM 
  table_google_apps
GROUP BY 
  target_id
```